# Adding new element to XML file using JAXB marshal is adding namespace to it

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have an existing xml file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person xmlns="http://Person">
    <name first="abc1",last="xyz1"/>
    <name first="abc2",last="xyz2"/>
</Person>
```

I need to add name element to it dynamically. I have implemented this as described below

1) Unmarshal the xml file

```
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Person> root = (JAXBElement<Person>) u.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        Person personObj = root.getValue();
```

2) Add the name element

```
        List<JAXBElement> nameList = personObj.getNameElement();
        Name name = new Name ();
        name.setFirst("abc3");
        name.setLast("xyz3");
        Name name1 = new Name ();
        name1.setFirst("abc4");
        name1.setLast("xyz4");      

        JAXBElement<Name> nameEle = new JAXBElement<Name>(new QName("Name"), Name.class, name);
        JAXBElement<Name> nameEle1 = new JAXBElement<Name>(new QName("Name"), Name.class, name1);

        nameList.add(nameEle);
        nameList.add(nameEle1);
```

3) marshal the file

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(personObj, newXMLFile);
```

Now marshalled xml is showing namespace to newly added elements. I want to know if there is a way to remove this namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person xmlns="http://Person">
    <name first="abc1",last="xyz1"/>
    <name first="abc2",last="xyz2"/>
    <name xmlns:ns2="http://Person" xmlns="" first="abc3",last="xyz3"/>
    <name xmlns:ns2="http://Person" xmlns="" first="abc4",last="xyz4"/>
</Person>
```

I want to keep the namespace at root element (Person) because the original xml has the namespace for root element

Comment: What JAXB classes/annotation are you using? Do you generate these from a schema? With JAXB you typically don't use `new JAXBElement<Name>(...)` but rather use POJO calls such as `nameList.add(new Name(...))`

Comment: The `QName` objects that you use to create your new elements do not look correct. You want the elements to be in the `http://Person` namespace so you should do `new QName("http://Person", "name")`

Comment: I don't want to see namespace for newly added elements thats why I am using new QName("Name") instead of new QName("http://Person", "name")

Comment: @imhotap, I generated these classes from a predefined xsd and personObj.getNameElement(); method returns List<JAXBElement<? extends BaseType>> nameList and is forcing me to add as JAXBElement. Any suggestion on how to use POJO calls is much appreciated

Comment: @Mohan Does your XSD use XML Schema wildcards rather than tight XSD types for name elements or does your bindings.xjb tell JAXB code generation to bind name elements to generic Java classes such as `java.lang.Object`? Maybe you could constrain the target types used for name elements in bindings.xjb

Comment: Because there is an `xmlns` attribute on the `Person` element which contains the `name` elements, the `name` elements are also in the `http://Person` namespace. That's just how XML works. Therefore, you want the `name` elements that you're adding to also be in the `http://Person` namespace, and not in an anonymous namespace (which is what you are doing now).

Comment: I figured it out to fix my issue using ObjectFactory as shown below ObjectFactory objectFactory=new ObjectFactory();
List<JAXBElement> nameList = personObj.getNameElement();
Name name = new Name ();
name.setFirst("abc3");
name.setLast("xyz3");
Name name1 = new Name ();
name1.setFirst("abc4");
name1.setLast("xyz4");
nameList .add(objectFactory.createName(name));
nameList .add(objectFactory.createName(name1));